# How to apply speed control to bicycle

Tags: speed, children

My 5 year kid rides bicycle in our street which is common in our locality, sometimes he tend to go for fast pedaling, which may harm himself and others as well, my question is how to make the bicycle go slower all the times for the sake of safety for everybody?

Comment: Well, your child will learn a lot about the mechanics of bicycles should you succeed - because he's gonna try to rip it off.

Comment: Any tampering with the equipment is likely to render the bicycle less safe. If you ride together in different scenarios you can teach appropriate speed and braking along with road awareness. My daughter only had to come off once to understand speed isn’t always fun

Comment: Welcome to parenthood.  It doesn't get any better as the kids grow, develop and learn how to interact with the real world.   Consider that limiting mr5 now means he might not develop risk assessment skills as well as otherwise.   The social part of this question might be more on-topic at https://parenting.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Part of growing up is doing stupid things for yourself, and 5 year olds are big fans of that. You're better off having learning what crashing at full-speed is like at this age when they are lighter and more durable than when older, as they aren't capable of significant speed to begin with. You don't need to resort to obscure technical measures.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the comments, I got some idea from the answers and comments

Answer (score 8):

Most bikes for small children only have a single gear which severely limits the speeds you can (comfortably) cycle at.

With a typical 28t chainring in the front, a 15t sprocket in the back and 16 inch wheels the maximum speed you can reach with fast pedaling (110rpm cadence) is about 16km/h. (minimum speed is around 11km/h at 75rpm, no wonder kids have to get off and push at steeper inclines)

16km/h is not terribly fast, that’s a speed a slightly older child can achieve on foot. Make him wear a helmet (properly! I see way too many children who wear it way too loose and at the back of the head) and the worst that’s going to happen is a scraped knee or palm. That’s assuming the area he’s riding in is safe, which would be a much bigger concern for me.

If you really wanted to you could change the gear ratio so he has to pedal even faster to reach speed. But that would ruin all the fun and utility. Right now his “comfortable” speed at the typical 90rpm pedaling cadence is already only 13km/h.

Comment: Thanks @Michael for the details, surely this will help me